# How to deserialize a string into a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, text

I have the below text:

```
id=1
familyName=Rooney
givenName=Wayne
middleNames=Mark
dateOfBirth=1985-10-24
dateOfDeath=
placeOfBirth=Liverpool
height=1.76
twitterId=@WayneRooney
```

Lines are separated by "\n" and pairs are separated by "=".

I have a Person class with properties like Id, FamilyName, GivenName, etc.

Is there any easy way to deserialize the above text into a Person object and later serializing a Person object to the above text with the correct line and pair separators?

I hoped there could be something like a TextSerializer?

Basically, I'd need to read a text from a file e.g. person1.txt then deserialize it into a Person object.

I'd like to avoid hardcoding it manually for each property if possible.
Thanks,

Comment: So, you are trying to read text from a file and store it in an array of object "FamilyInfo" or something?

Comment: I read a text from a file e.g. person1.txt then need to deserialize it into a Person object.

Comment: what separates each `Person` instance in the file, or is there only one per file?

Comment: there is one person per file.

Comment: ahh, did you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: I think it unlikely that there's an off-the-shelf solution for a custom schema such as yours.

Comment: @happy coder; it's not an xml serializer.

Comment: Well, could you turn it into an XML file first then?

Comment: [Create your own formatter.](http://geekswithblogs.net/luskan/archive/2007/07/16/113956.aspx)

Comment: This format is similar to [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). You might be able to trick [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/) into doing the job for you, but you have to ask "is this working by contract or by coincidence?" I would probably just code it myself; it's not a lot of work.

Comment: You have control over the creation of this file? It seems that my answer can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection can help here, without hardcoding the propery names and using third party libraries

```
var person = Deserialize<Person2>("a.txt");
```

---

```
T Deserialize<T>(string fileName)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
    {
        var keyVal = line.Split('=');
        if (keyVal.Length != 2) continue;

        var prop = type.GetProperty(keyVal[0].Trim());
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(keyVal[1], prop.PropertyType));
        }
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
```

---

```
public class Person2
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string familyName { set; get; }
    public string givenName { set; get; }
    public string middleNames { set; get; }
    public string dateOfBirth { set; get; }
    public string dateOfDeath { set; get; }
    public string placeOfBirth { set; get; }
    public double height { set; get; }
    public string twitterId { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Using Reflection would be an interesting approach. CustomPersonSerializer

Comment: @TheLight In fact it can be used to deserialize any object (`Deserialize<AntType>`), Therefore I wouldn't use `Person` in the name. Maybe `PrimitiveSerializer`?

Comment: Can you pass an interface in rather than a concrete class? It fails on the line Activator.CreateInstance(type). How to create an object from an interface?

Comment: @TheLight Suppose you can pass an interface, How do you think the code should find the concrete class (An instance of an interface can not be created) which implements that interface. Other built-in serializers do not accept an interface too, just for the same reason.

Comment: @TheLight Also Suppose i added code to search all assemblies for a type that implements that interface. What if there are two classes that implement this interface. which one should be created?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution too.
If possible, you can try to format your text as json in creation.
So you do not need all this treatment. Just use [Json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/)

```
public class Person
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public string familyName { set; get; }
    public string givenName { set; get; }
    public string middleNames { set; get; }
    public string dateOfBirth { set; get; }
    public string dateOfDeath { set; get; }
    public string placeOfBirth { set; get; }
    public double height { set; get; }
    public string twitterId { set; get; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string line;
        string newText = "{";

        System.IO.StreamReader file =  new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            newText += line.Insert(line.IndexOf("=") + 1, "\"") + "\",";

        }
        file.Close();

        newText = newText.Remove(newText.Length -1);
        newText = newText.Replace("=", ":");
        newText += "}";


        Person Person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(newText);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That's interesting, you've first converted it to JSON format which is an easier approach to serialization.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you have several options:

1. Load the file, convert it to XML that would work with an XMLSerializer/DataContract
2. Write your own Serializer with IFormatter
3. Do it manually by reading the file (Example below)

   class Person
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string FamilyName { get; set; }

   ```
   public Person(string file)
   {
       if (!File.Exists(file))
           return;

       string[] personData = File.ReadAllLines(file);

       foreach (var item in personData)
       {
           string[] itemPair = item.Split('='); //do some error checking here to see if = isn't appearing twice
           string itemKey = itemPair[0];
           string itemValue = itemPair[1];
           switch (itemKey)
           {
               case "familyName":
                   this.FamilyName = itemValue;
                   break;
               case "id":
                   this.ID = int.Parse(itemValue);
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }

       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I'm having an issue formatting the first lines of the code, but you get the gist.

Comment: *`I'd like to avoid hardcoding it manually for each property if possible`*