# How to read in an object by its members' names?

Tags: c#, io

How to read in an object by its member variables' names from a text file? For example, I have a class Point with X, Y, Z properties. And I can read a point by

```
 Z = 1; X = 2; Y = 3;
```

Or is there any existing libraries to do similar things?

I think I can use Console to read a line or lines and then parse the lines. Is there any pattern or generic templates that I can make it automatic for any class.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what "read a point by ..."  means. Please show a more full example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Json and XML are two standard ways of writing out and reading in data (serialization).

Comment: It *sounds* like you're trying to deserialize an object from a text file (or just read each "object" line by line?). If so, close your question and look up deserialization. There are many C# examples on this site as well as tutorials on the web to do this.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp): `pointInstance.GetType().GetProperty(propNameFromTextFile).GetValue(pointInstance, null)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize a string into a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708748/how-to-deserialize-a-string-into-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change how object is represented *as text* (the right term is *serialized*), I would say that the nearest standarized serialization format to your custom one is [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).

For example, your object would be serialized as follows:

```
Point:
   Z: 1
   X: 2
   Y: 3
```

And there's a serializer/deserializer for .NET called [YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet).

Otherwise, I would go with JSON:

```
{ z: 1, x: 2, y: 3 }
```

...which can be deserialized with the well-known and mature [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Comment: Just browse some examples in the JSON link. It is easy to use. Does it include version control? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020 No, it's just serialization